# Restore Doctrine connection after failed flush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.8

When a entityManager does a `flush` and this flush throws an exception. The doctrine entity manager will catch this exception clear the unit of work and `mark the connection` as closed and then doing the rollback (https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/v2.5.6/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L412-L417).

I need to restore the connection but as there is no method with does `$this->closed = false` in the entityManager I'm confused how to handle this that after a failed `flush` I can `flush` another entity to mark this to mark in the database a specific task as failed! Also I can not run multiple tasks when a previous one failed the other can not run when when using the entityManager.

**TL;DR** So what is the best practice to restore the connection after a failed flush? As I see it is just marked as closed and is still connected but I dont want to use something dirty like Reflection or an custom entity manager to restore my connection.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Function `resetManager`  Like This `$this->getDoctrine()->resetManager()` 
more detail in this [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5339)

***edit***

lets say Exemple its a table has a date field As DateTime and not null

```
    $Exemple = new Exemple();
    $Exemple->setDate(null);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    try {
        $em->persist($Exemple);
        $em->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();
    }
    $Exemple->setDate(new \DateTime());
    $em->persist($Exemple);
    $em->flush();
```

whith `$this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();` the data its flushed in database 
without `$this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();` we get **The EntityManager is closed**.

Comment: You can certainly do this.  Won't help a bit.  Once an exception is thrown there is no way to continue to use the entity manager.  Down voted accordingly.

Comment: hi @Cerad Can you plz provide a documention that prove that we can't use getManager after exception throw because im using resetManager in my code and its work i will edit my answer to put a small exemple

Comment: It is a bit hard to parse the original question but I am pretty sure he does not want a new entity manager.  Let's see if he responds.

Comment: It's impossible to use entity manager that has failed in transaction. You have to reset it, then get the new instance, as told in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give it a try the problem I currently see is that the entity manager is not used in the same class I catch the exception and where I can reset the manager so I think the other class will not get the new manager, but I will give it a try.

Comment: In that case the entity manager can't get the reset instance. so like they say: The best is to avoid getting a closed entity manager (which means validating your data before sending them to the database)

Comment: As my library just loop through tasks and run them I'm not able to validate the data. So a programmer of a specific task could have forget to validate something and this will influence other tasks but seems like I need go the evil way an run each task itself calling a command with "exec".

Comment: I removed my down vote now that the original author has clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, first, catch in your method if it throws an exception, after that, you could check if the connection is still open, otherwise, redefine it.

```
 $result = $this->functionABC();// catch if it throws an exception

 $oEntityManager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
 $bEntityManagerIsOpen = $oEntityManager->isOpen();
 if (!$bEntityManagerIsOpen) {
     $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->resetManager();
     $oEntityManager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
 }
```

I have used this way in a Command using Symfony2.8 and it works properly for me.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will try this but I'm not sure if this works when the manager is used in another service and I don't think that the service will get the new manager?